# What is the most efficient way to store data with an unknown schema in a React Native app?

Tags: react-native

I'm facing a problem while developing an app in React Native - I'm not sure what kind of local (persisted) storage I should use. The data I'm trying to fetch is sensitive, so it needs to be encrypted. Additionally, I don't know what properties the objects will contain, so I'm not convinced that using SQL-like engines is the best option.

MMKV sounds cool, but in the end, I'm not sure if string parsing a huge amount of non-paginated data is a good idea. Also, filtering that amount of data in-memory doesn't feel right.

Data needs to be encrypted in device storage. It gets synchronized every time user logs in. It need to be persisted during session. Records might get updated or even deleted during user session. All data gets wiped when user logs out. It does not need to be persisted between sessions or app installs.

What approach would be most efficient? Is using SQL-like engine is inevitable in this case?

Comment: Can you say more about your requirements? Does the data need to persist between sessions or app installs? Does it need to be encrypted in device storage? Also, your question may be closed because asking "what approach should I take" leads to opinion-based answers, which are discouraged.

Comment: No, data does not need to persist between sessions or app installs. It synchronizing after user logs in. Records may get updated or removed during session, but all data get wiped when user logs out. Yes, it does need to be encrypted in device storage. Sorry for the "approach" question, I didn't think it over. I did edit original question.

Comment: How much data are we talking about? Does it need to persist when the app is closed, or is it okay to re-download the data when the app is foregrounded again?

Comment: No, amount of data is large. We are taking about 100 000 - 200 000 records. It often takes about 2-3 minutes to download on good wi-fi network.